# In an Xcode mac osx AppleScript app (AppleScriptObjC), what is the command to I minimize the main app window?

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript, minimize, applescript-objc

I'm trying to write an app that should keep running after a button is clicked so I want to minimize it. I have the app main window theWindow connected to the placeholder

```
property theWindow : missing value
```

I have tried:

```
theWindow's performMiniaturize()
theWindow's miniaturize()
```

But I keep getting the message:

> [NSView performMiniaturize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x608000120280 (error -10000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[-[NSWindow miniaturize:]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419426-miniaturize?language=objc)

```
theWindow's miniaturize: me
```

That said, why don't you just close the window and reopen it later if/as needed? (Make sure your app isn't configured to quit automatically when the window closes, of course.)

Comment: That did the trick, and thank you for the suggestion to optimize the app.
Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

miniaturize() is correct in ASOC. But you Call it on a view (NSView), not a window - thats what the error says.

To get the window you can either climb up the view hirarchy like this

```
set window to view's superview()
```

where variable view is what you called window by mistake. But note: this will only work if the next level is the window and not another NSView.

Or you can get the main window like that:

```
if exists (1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true) then tell (1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true) to miniaturize()
```

Comment: The suggested command causes a compilation error:
error: Expected “,” but found “"”. (-2741)